# Initialize a Video.js player on a ajax loaded part of the page

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

The video player actually loads fine. My actual problem is when I refresh some parts of my page with AJAX and those parts contains a video player, the HTML5 player loads fine, but not the [Video.js](http://videojs.com/) part that customizes it.

The video.js file is loaded in the header of the page. I have read the doc and can't find how to initialize a video player on a page that has already been loaded. Isn't there a `myPlayer.initialize()` kind of function I can call when my part of page containing the video is loaded to make the video player load correctly with Video.js?

I think the video.js file does it automatically only on page load.

Thanks for your precious help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, according to the docs you can do:

```
videojs("example_video_1", {}, function(){
  // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
});
```

It's specifically to be used with dynamic content :)

Source: http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html (at the bottom)

Comment: It does work, thank you! I had another problem, but I found I was giving same id to all my videos.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem. My scenario:

Loading thru ajax a html code with the video tag, it works the first time, but when I reaload the content with ajax (not refreshing the page) it doesn't work.

What I did was to switch to finding the video thru the class, since the ID becomes changed by videojs.

So this is my call now:

```
videojs(document.getElementsByClassName("video-js")[0], {}, function(){
          // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
});
```

Hope this helps someone with the same problem where [Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479618/bruno) solution didn't worked.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! this solutions is the right one for my case.

Comment: Bravo! Tank you so much. This solution is correct for 'refresh' problems.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked, the accepted answer did not. Wasted a half a day trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 3):

I did it in a loop

```js
var massVideo = $('.video-js');
for(var i = 0; i < massVideo.length; i++){
  videojs(massVideo[i]).ready(function(){});
}
```