# Multiple initialization of Video.js player on ajax loaded part of page

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, load, video.js

A similar question asked [Jean-François](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035946/initialize-a-video-js-player-on-a-ajax-loaded-part-of-the-page) a few months ago, but my Problem is some more tricky.
I have to load different content in a node named 'ajax Content'.
The first time the player was initialized and the video has shown with its own skin of the control bar.
But if another film or the same one a second time is loaded, the Video.js script is not  initialized and running.
This happens also if i clear the node with 'remove()' or 'empty()'.
This is the part of the external html-file:

```
<div id="video">
<video id="html5_video" class="video-js vjs-ms-skin" autoplay controls preload>
    <source src="fileadmin/themen/de/iagos.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
<div class="ajaxLoadClose"></div>
```

This is the jQuery-script

```
$(".ajax-content").load(pfad+"#video",function(responce,status,xhr){
if (status=="success")
{

    _V_("html5_video");
    $(".ajax-content").css("display","block");
    $(".ajaxLoadClose").click(function() {
        var vidBig = $(this).parent().find("video").get(0);
        vidBig.pause();
        $(".ajax-content").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('.ajax-content').children().remove();
        });/**/
    });
}
```

});

Is there any kind of reset? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

If you're creating a new player for each video without going to a new page, it would start to build up player instances because references to the players are stored in the `_V_.players` object by their ID. if you call `player.destroy()` it will remove the player reference. Just make sure you don't have anything else referencing the player sticking around. You'll also want to remove the player .video-js div from the page. In later versions the player.destroy() function will do that too.

Refer [this](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/questions/415-init-video-on-ajax-load) for detailed discussions. :)